# Combining class names in Vue Render Function

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-render-function

I have a Vue 2 component using the render function like so:

```
export default {
  name: "u-skeleton",
  render(createElement) {
    return createElement("div", {
      attrs: {
        class: "skeleton"
      },
    });
  },
};
```

When I use the component like so:

```
<u-skeleton class="foo"/>
```

The HTML output is:

```
<div class="foo"/>
```

How can I get it to be this, so that the CSS class names are combined?

```
<div class="foo skeleton"/>
```

It would be helpful to know the answer in Vue 2 and 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using a render function, `class` is a special attribute that has its own property in the [options object](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html#The-Data-Object-In-Depth):

```js
render(createElement) {
  return createElement("div", {
    class: 'skeleton'
  });
}
```

Instead of `attrs`, use the `class` property which can be:

> a string, object, or array of strings and objects.